# How to reference only affected rows in AFTER UPDATE trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, trigger, row-modification-time

I have this table:

[image]

And I'm trying to create an update trigger which will update `last_updated_on = GETDATE()` and `last_updated_by = SYSTEM_USER` columns whenever an update is performed on `step_number` or `step_name` column.

I started creating it by

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_app_bread_crumbs_afterupdate
ON [dbo].[app_bread_crumbs]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE [dbo].[app_bread_crumbs]
    SET last_updated_by = SYSTEM_USER,
    last_updated_on = GETDATE()
END
```

But this will update all rows at once. I'm trying to figure out how to specify to only update `last_updated_on` and `last_updated_by` by the trigger for the specific row where updates are being made.

For example if they update:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[app_bread_crumbs]
    SET step_name = 'DAMAGE' WHERE step_number = 1
```

Only first row should be updated by the trigger

Answer (score 10):

Use the `inserted` table, which is a special table available inside triggers containing the rows that will be updated/inserted into the table.

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_app_bread_crumbs_afterupdate
ON [dbo].[app_bread_crumbs]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE [dbo].[app_bread_crumbs]
    SET last_updated_by = SYSTEM_USER,
    last_updated_on = GETDATE()
    FROM dbo.app_bread_crumbs abc
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i WHERE i.id = abc.id);
END
```

Comment: Since they want to log the user and the time only when specific columns are updated, perhaps it would be a good idea to suggest the UPDATE() function as well.

Comment: ...or a join to `inserted` making sure those values have changed, because `UPDATE()` returns true if a column is mentioned, regardless of whether the value actually changed.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `INSERTED`and `DELETED` pseudo-tables. One way to do this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_app_bread_crumbs_afterupdate
ON [dbo].[app_bread_crumbs]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE upd
    SET last_updated_by = SYSTEM_USER,
        last_updated_on = GETDATE()
    FROM [dbo].[app_bread_crumbs] AS upd
      JOIN Inserted AS i
        ON i.id = upd.id
      JOIN Deleted AS d
        ON d.id = i.id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS                              -- only when any      
            ( SELECT i.sep_number, i.step_name    -- of the 2 columns
            INTERSECT                             -- changed
              SELECT d.sep_number, d.step_name
            ) ;
END ;
```